# Cyrillic symbols in jsonrpc response

Tags: java, android, android-studio, encoding, android-json-rpc

Using **Android Studio** and **alexd-jsonrpc** client I recieve a response, where cyrillic symbols looks like:

```
{..."ticket_info=ÐÐ¾ÐºÑ 1"...}
```

instead of:

```
{..."ticket_info=Мойщик 1"...}
```

How can i decode this to cyrillic?

JSONRPC request code:

```
JSONRPCClient client = JSONRPCClient.create(_server, JSONRPCParams.Versions.VERSION_2);
client.setConnectionTimeout(2000);
client.setSoTimeout(2000);
_workplaceList = client.callJSONArray("GetWorkplaceList", companyID);
```

Comment: I don't know much about this library, but this is a character encoding problem. Can't you create a client for which you specify the expected encoding of the responses?

Comment: You posted the code for the request. But you complain about the response. I think you should show the code for getting the response.

Comment: No problem with response, because I tested it on another clients - there were no encoding problems >,<

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an encoding problem.  Verify that the service is encoding the  JSON-RPC response as UTF-8 and that JSONRPCClient is configured to expect UTF-8.